# Create and run alias file for command line

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I have created a file "~/.aliases" file with the content:

```
# git stuff
alias ga="git add"
alias gaa="git add ."
```

in "~/.bashrc" at the top I have this code.

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

. ~/.aliases
```

I thought this should work but when I run, for example, `gaa` in the command line, I get an error.

```
No command 'gaa' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gav' from package 'gav' (universe)
 Command 'gap' from package 'gap-core' (universe)
 Command 'gpa' from package 'gpa' (universe)
 Command 'aa' from package 'astronomical-almanac' (universe)
 Command 'gac' from package 'gap-dev' (universe)
 Command 'gak' from package 'gui-apt-key' (universe)
gaa: command not found
```

Comment: Have you run `. ~/.bashrc` or reopened the terminal afterwards?

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thank you for the fast reply @kos

Comment: You're welcome. I found a duplicate question which contains this answer already, please accept the closure so that people finding this question will be redirected to that answer.